# Can someone identify this grub please

Tags: pests, insects

I found this critter in a planter full of wet compost. So far theres about 10. I was going to plant strawberries in it. I’d like to know if it is something cool or something that likes strawberries and I need to move elsewhere. Im in UK ESSEX [image: grub]